# Are there Target Date Funds in Europe/Germany?

Tags: germany, europe, target-date-fund

The title already says it.

To expand on this, I read about target date funds on this site. Essentially, they try to provide bigger gains with bigger risks at the start, and "automatically" become more conservative, the closer the target date comes.

As far as I know, in Germany, we have several funds with different risk strategies made specifically for retirement (e. g. from the DekaBank), but the shift towards more conservative strategies, I have to do on my own.

Isn't there such a product in Germany, and if not, why? Is it maybe due to regulations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I didn't do the appropriate research.

There are products called "Zielfonds" (nearly the same name, 1:1 translated) or "Lebenszyklusfonds" (life cycle fund) which offer about the same functionality. However, they do so by specifying a range of years (e. g. 2014-2019, 2045-2050 and so on).

Edit: Be aware that "Zielfonds" is also used for the components of a "Dachfonds" (fund of fonds). What adds to this confusion is the fact that some target date funds may actually be funds of funds, and vice versa.

Comment: From my limited experience in the UK, it's not so much that _funds_ change their investment/risk profile over their lifetime (although there may be some that do), but more that things like _pension plans_ change their investment profile in different funds/shares/stocks etc. to reflect the desired "life-time" risk profile.

Comment: @TripeHound A pension plan is what its name says - a plan for getting a pension, i. e. money after retirement. Target date funds are more flexible: you can not only set them up for retirement, but also for the 18th birthday of your child or other similar events.